# Json.stringify very slow in EJS parsing

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, ejs, stringify

Im rendering an EJS in my node.js express app like so,

```
 res.render('chart' ,{"data":result})
```

inside my ejs document.ready function i do,

```
    var myObj = <%- JSON.stringify(data)%>
```

Problem is this JSON.stringify function is very slow and takes about 2 minutes to parse my data and also BLOCKS my eventloop (meaning other requests are put on hold until this finishes). Is there any other way around this problem. In essence, I need a way to perform stringify function without blocking eventloop and do it swiftly.

Comment: see https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream

Comment: You can try using the web worker is. In this case, if the source data is large, then the result will have to cook inside worker`s. https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads